# Sprintf in Perl doesn't display hexadecimal character properly

Tags: perl, printf

I have a code like this.

```
     $entry = &function();   //returns a number between 0 to 20
     $var = sprintf("%#.4x", $entry);
     if($var=~ /$hex/)
     {
         //block of statements
      }
```

$hex will be within 0x0000 ..... 0x0014. Now, when `function` returns from 1 to 20, $var matches $hex. (Like 0x0001 .... 0x0014)

But when $entry is 0, $var becomes `0000`. But I want it to be `0x0000`. Currently, I am checking if that is `0000`, I am changing it through a if loop. Please let me know if that is possible in sprintf itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the documentation for [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html):

> **flags**
>   #     prefix non-zero hexadecimal with "0x" or "0X"

Note that it says `non-zero`, so only non-zero values will be prefixed by `0x`.

A simple fix is to add the prefix manually:

```
sprintf "0x%04x", $entry;
```

Comment: I have choosen this answer, since it covers explanation as well as a solution for zero.

Answer (score 2):

The doc clearly mentions that `0x` is appended only for non-zero numbers when `#` flag is used.This makes sense since zero is zero whether it is in Octal or Hexadecimal. Hence prefixing it with `0x` doesn't make sense.

Best way to handle this would be:

```
if($var=~ /$hex/ or !$var)
```

Comment: In our script, there is a literal match function which we have to make use of, checks for 0x0000, doesn't consider that as equal to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are doing things backwards. Wouldn't the following make more sense?

```
if ($entry == hex($hex))
```

If you want to compare numbers, compare the numbers, not their text representation.

Comment: Sorry, We are comparing output from a device with the expected one. So, `match is done literally`, meaning that except difference in number of spaces, each and every character in a line has to be matched as they are.  No evaluation of number or strings is done. Our framework is like that. I gave a small example to get to know about it.

Comment: Cool. I'll leave this here anyway in case it helps anyone else.